# else no cumple su función correctamente

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando hacer correr un código y he agregado 2 `if` y un `else`, los `if` me trabajan bien y hacen su función pero el `else` se ejecuta sin que se cumpla su condición.

Solo necesito que el `else` me muestre un diálogo en caso de que los `if` no se ejecuten, el cual es su función como tal.
¿alguna idea?

Acá anexo el código completo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int alumnos, menor1=0, mayor1=0, edad, mayor2, menor2;
int mujer, hombre;
char sexo[20];
char const* error;


int main ()

{
  cout<<"ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ";
    cin>>alumnos;
    cout<<"\n";

    for (int num2=1; num2<=alumnos; num2++)
    {
        cout<<"\nDATOS DEL ALUMNO "<<num2<<": "<<endl;
        cout<<"\ningrese su sexo: ";
        cin>>sexo;
        cout<<"ingrese la edad del alumno: ";
        cin>>edad;


        for (int num1=0; num1<=alumnos; num1++)
        {

//if dedicado al calculo de las mujeres!

            if (stricmp(sexo,"mujer") == 0)
            {

            if (edad > mayor1)
            {
                mayor1 = edad;
                menor1 = edad;
            }

            if (edad < menor1)
            {
                menor1 = edad;
            }           
            }

// if dedicado al calculo de los hombres!

            if (stricmp(sexo,"hombre") == 0)
            {

            if (edad > mayor2)
            {
                mayor2 = edad;
                menor2 = edad;
            }

            if (edad < menor2)
            {
                menor2 = edad;
            }           
            }

//else para hacer en caso de que los if no se cumplan y finalizacion del codigo

            else
            {
                error == "Alumno invalidado por sexo mal colocado! solo ingrese si es hombre o mujer";
            }

        }
        cout<<error<<endl;

    }

    cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\nPROMEDIO DE EDAD EN MUJERES"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nel promedio es desde "<<menor1<<" hasta "<<mayor1<<" anos"<<endl;

    cout<<"\n\nPROMEDIO DE EDAD EN HOMBRES"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nel promedio es desde "<<menor2<<" hasta "<<mayor2<<" anos"<<endl;

getch ();   

}
```

Comment: `error = "...";` ? Por cierto, te recomiendo que le des formato a tu código en producción.

Comment: El `else` cumple su función correctamente, es tu código el que está mal. Esto es un caso de "[*select isn't broken*](https://lingpipe-blog.com/2007/06/27/select-isnt-broken-or-horses-not-zebras/)".

Answer (score 3):

El problema no es que el `else` no esté funcionando correctamente, sino que estás utilizando la estructura condicional "incorrecta".

Ahora mismo estás usando dos `if` independientes y el `else` sólo se aplica al segundo (y funciona correctamente como debe):

```
if (stricmp(sexo,"mujer") == 0)
{
     .....
}

if (stricmp(sexo,"hombre") == 0)
{
    ......
}
else
{
     ......
}
```

Lo que quieres hacer es utilizar un `if..else if..else` y en ese caso el será una única estructura donde el `else` "aplicará" a ambos `if` en lugar de ser dos estructuras independientes y el `else` solo aplicar a una de ellas. Algo como esto:

```
if (stricmp(sexo,"mujer") == 0)
{
     .....
}
else if (stricmp(sexo,"hombre") == 0)
{
    ......
}
else
{
     ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que el else se ejecuta cuando sexo vale "mujer".

Vamos a verlo con un programa más simplificado :

```
if (stricmp(sexo,"mujer") == 0)
{
  cout << "Soy mujer" << endl;
}

if (stricmp(sexo,"hombre") == 0)
{
  cout << "Soy hombre" << endl;
}
else
{
  cout << "No soy ni hombre ni mujer" << endl;
}
```

En este programa el else va con el segundo if. Es decir, si sexo es "mujer" el primer if se cumple y por tanto imprime "mujer" y el segundo if no se cumple y por tanto se ejecuta el else del segundo if e imprime "No soy ni hombre ni mujer".

Para que haga lo que quieres debes escribirlo así :

```
if (stricmp(sexo,"mujer") == 0)
{
  cout << "Soy mujer" << endl;
}
else {
  if (stricmp(sexo,"hombre") == 0)
  {
    cout << "Soy hombre" << endl; 
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "No soy ni hombre ni mujer" << endl;
  }
}
```

Ahora el else de "No soy hombre ni mujer" se ejecutará solo si los dos ifs son falsos.